# how to resolve not showing correctly image in chrome on apple mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

my gallery image in apple's chrome not showing correctly. images stretch in apple mobile.
I used in HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-md-column justify-content-center flex-wrap">
   <img src="images/listings/yyVxA_1609070447.webp">
</div>
```

and Css:

```
max-width: 100%;height: auto;
```

Comment: Hi @haniye, welcome to the SO community. If you ask questions, please provide all the information that is necessary to understand and, in the best case, reproduce your problem. For example which CSS selectors do you use, and it seems like you are using a CSS library (Tailwind, Bootstrap). Please mention information like this as well. Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-md-column justify-content-center flex-wrap image"> <!-- added the image class -->
   <img src="images/listings/yyVxA_1609070447.webp" width="400px" height="200px"> <!-- default width + height -->
</div>
```

Furthermore, if you want to be more specific, use the [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) query in CSS - like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

This will change the class when the the width of a user's screen is 600px. Though you normally don't need to do this with images if they have the width of 100% and auto height. You may want to read [how to make an image responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp).